# How to get the orders above the order id and How to use the limit in magento 2

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento2.2.6, query

I need to write code to get next 10 orders above the given order id.

```
<?php


namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    //~ \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    )
{
    //~ $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
     //~ $orders = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',  array('from'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2018-01-01')), 'to'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2019-01-01'))));   // Getting first order
     //~ $orders = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',  array('gt'=>0)); 
     $orders = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->setPageSize(1)->setCurPag‌​e(10)->getCollection()->load(); 
     echo "Count is ". count($orders);
     foreach($orders as $order)
     {

         $gross = $order->getGrandTotal();
         $tax = $order->getTaxAmount();
         $net = $gross - $tax;
         $payment = $order->getPayment();
         $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
         $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();

         echo "<br/>gross :". $gross;
         echo "<br/>tax :". $tax;
         echo "<br/>net :". $net;
         echo "<br/>Created :". $order->getCreatedAt();
         echo "<br/>state :". $order->getState();
         echo "<br/>payment methodTitle :". $methodTitle;
         echo "<br/> Customer : ". $order->getCustomerId();
         echo "<br/>Items in order";

         $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            $itemid =  $orderItem->getId();
            echo "Item id" .$orderItem->getId() . "<br />";
        }
    }    


    echo "Hello World";
    exit;
}
```

}

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if its working or not.

Comment: Please click on "right sign" also in my answer for accept answer if it's useful for you. So, it will useful for other developer also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `addFieldToFilter()` instead of `addAttributeToFilter()`. Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    .........
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    .........
) {
    .........
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    .........
}
public function execute() {
    $ordercollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'))->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['gt' => $orderid]);
    $ordercollection->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
    $ordercollection->setPageSize(10);
    foreach ($ordercollection as $order) {
        $gross = $order->getGrandTotal();
        $tax = $order->getTaxAmount();
        $net = $gross - $tax;

        echo "gross :" . $gross;
        echo "<br/>tax :" . $tax;
        echo "<br/>net :" . $net;
        echo "<br/>Created :" . $order->getCreatedAt();

        echo "Items in order";

        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            echo $orderItem->getId() . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while i use "\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory"  in __construct i face error. Shall i load any thing before the __construct . I am working in magento module

Comment: Did you remove generated folder? execute this command : rm -rf generated/

Comment: No i am not remove that folder

Comment: You need to remove generated folder and flush cache when you change something in construct.

Comment: Execute this command : rm -rf generated/ and php bin/magento c:f

Comment: You mean i need to remove rootfolder/generated. folder

Comment: Yes and then flush cache. You can underscore that folder if you need to take backup of that.

Comment: I did after that i face the following error 
ReflectionException: Class Magento\Store\Model\Group\Interceptor does not exist in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86052/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-sammu-sundar).